# How to check if every item pandas column of lists is an int?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column of lists. I need to check if every item in those lists are ints.

For a regular list, I can find if an item is an int using

```
all(isinstance(x, int) for x in lst)
```

and for a regular pandas column, I can check if they're all ints using

```
df.loc[~df['Field1'].str.isdigit(), 'Field1']
```

But what if the column contains a list in each row?

Edit:

He is a minimal reproducable example

```
A = np.random.randint(0,40,20)                                      
B = [np.random.randint(0,40,k) for k in np.random.randint(2,20,20)]

A32 = A.astype(np.int32)

from itertools import chain

sizes = np.fromiter(chain((0,),map(len,B)),np.int32,len(B)+1)
boundaries = sizes.cumsum()

# force int32
B_all = np.empty(boundaries[-1],np.int32)
B32 = np.split(B_all, boundaries[1:-1])
df = pd.DataFrame([A32, B32]).T
df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x: x.tolist() )
df.columns = ['a', 'b']
df.at[10,'b'] = [ 3, 5, 2, 1, 'a', 4, 4]
```

Comment: Can you come up with a [mcve] ?

Comment: I agree with harvpan. We need more info. Be sure to include example data.

Comment: updated with example

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` with your current list check:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

# create random df
x = [{'A': [random.randint(0,300) for i in range(10)]} for i in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)

df.A.apply(lambda x: all(isinstance(y, int) for y in x))
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
8    True
9    True

# add non-int row
x = [{'A': [random.randint(0,300) for i in range(10)]} for i in range(10)] + [{'A':[chr(a) for a in range(100,120)]}]

df = pd.DataFrame(x)

df.A.apply(lambda x: all(isinstance(y, int) for y in x))
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a function and apply it should work:

```
def check_list(lst):
    return all(isinstance(x, int) for x in lst)

df['is_all_ints'] = df['Field1'].apply(check_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `callable` to `.loc` like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [[1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1], [1, 2, "a"]],
    "b": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
})

df.loc[
    lambda df: df["a"].apply(
        lambda lst: all(isinstance(item, int) for item in lst)
    )
]
```

Result:

```
           a  b
0  [1, 2, 3]  a
1  [1, 1, 1]  b
2  [3, 2, 1]  c
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `map` and `pd.api.types.is_integer`

```
df['b'].map(lambda lst: all(map(pd.api.types.is_integer, lst)))

Out[299]:
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10    False
11     True
12     True
13     True
14     True
15     True
16     True
17     True
18     True
19     True
Name: b, dtype: bool
```